# Get the content of a text box, create a .txt file from it and store it in a folder

Tags: php, html, forms, textbox, directory

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <label for="subject1" >Subject:</label>
      <input type="text" name="subject1" id="subject1">

    </form>
```

This is my form. I need to get what user writes in it, make a txt file and in that txt file I need to writher that text he entered. thx

ofc useing php

any1 ganna help?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you create the directory path and then use a writer to write the contents to that specific path

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath);
    StreamWriter writer;

    writer = File.CreateText(appPath + "*.txt"); //AppendText to not overwrite the text
```

Comment: he need answer in PHP